# how to get question un-held?

Tags: discussion

I asked [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1217104/read-and-format-xml-backup-of-sms-messages) yesterday and it was put "on hold" by a moderator.   I edited the question to remove the offending language and make the question more clear, but the question is still "on hold."

Is there any way (or any point) to get a question off the "on hold" status?  Or once a moderator gives you the magic finger, is your question doomed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your edits the question has been placed in a review queue where people with sufficient reputation (> 3000) can vote to either reopen or leave closed.

In this particular case I have reopened your question after your edit.

---

#### What does it mean if a question is "closed" or "on hold"?

> Questions are marked [on hold] for the first five days after closure
>   to encourage edits and improvements to the question.
>
> If a question is edited by the original poster when it is marked [on
>   hold], it will automatically be placed in a review queue to be
>   considered for reopening. If it is not reopened within five days, the
>   [on hold] notice automatically changes to [closed].
>
> There is functionally no difference between an [on hold] question and
>   a [closed] one; neither can be answered until it is re-opened, but
>   they both allow comments, votes and edits.

Source [What does it mean if a question is "closed" or "on hold"?](https://superuser.com/help/closed-questions)

Comment: Thank you for your consideration.